# A function is not being called

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I got a CCNode subclass, and it eventually calls a function located on its parent. First, my class will do this:

```
-(void)getTargetPosition {
    Battle *myParent = (Battle *)self.parent;
    position = [myParent getTargetPosition:@"ENEMY"];
}
```

Where *Battle* is the parent (a CCLayer).

And here's the code for the function *getTargetPosition* in the parent:

```
-(CGPoint)getTargetPosition:(NSString*)target {
    NSLog(@"I AM RUNNING");
    CGPoint position;
    if ([target isEqualToString:@"ENEMY"]) {
        position = ccp(400,250);
    }else if ([target isEqualToString:@"ALLY"]) {
        position = ccp(240,160);
    }
    return position;
}
```

But there is this problem: *getTargetPosition* is, for some reason, never called. I can tell since the NSLog "I AM RUNNING" never displays.

Any ideas why is that method not running?

The functions are all declared on the .h file already. XCode throws me no warnings/errors.

Comment: Where are you calling the `-(void)getTargetPosition`? Because it isn't being called either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is self.parent (and thus myParent) nil? Then the method would not be called.

Comment: Yep, that's almost certainly what's happening.  It's a "cute" feature of Objective-C that a call on a nil pointer is silently NO-OPed (and returns zero/nil), vs throwing an exception.  This is handy in some cases, but conceals a whole boatload of bugs.

Comment: Ah. Thank you, that was the problem. Apparently I was trying to call that *before* adding that class as child of the scene.